# Android. dispatchKeyEvent. event.getAction(). Какой KeyEvent у нижнего почерка? ("_")

Tags: android

Подскажите, какой KeyEvent у "_". Тире нашел, оно в виде KEYCODE_MINUS. А вот с нижним почерком понять не могу.

Comment: Теоретически '_' - это SHIFT + '-'. Пробуйте как-то так: `dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0,0,KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MINUS,0,KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_ON))`

Comment: Я принимаю event.getKeyCode(). Из него надо понять, когда пришел _ .   `if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MINUS) {...}`. А как понять, когда приходит _  ?

Comment: А тогда причём тогда dispatchKeyEvent в заголовке? `if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MINUS && event.isShiftPressed()) {...}` - так попробуйте.

Comment: Да, точно, все четко - как надо! Спасибо  **woesss**!